# Why do base64 encoded strings use the characters + and /?

Tags: base64, conventions

Does anyone know what's the reason [base64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64#Base64table) encoded strings uses the characters `+` and `/` ?

Why not `@` and `#`, or `^` and `*` ?

Comment: Why not? It's arbitrary.

Comment: @HotLicks yes that's what I was talking about, which tradition did it follow?

Comment: Actually, there were (and still are, to a degree) several variants of the "standard".  Largely the choice would have been arbitrary, but it would depend, to a significant degree, on what protocol it was being embedded in, as discussed in ibid's post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The stated design goal for base64 is given in the MIME RFCs and their precedessors.  The earliest I found is [RFC 1113](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1113), whose encoding method was reused almost without change in MIME base64.  Quoting the oldest MIME RFC, [RFC 1341](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1341)

> NOTE:  This subset has the important  property  that  it  is
> represented   identically   in  all  versions  of  ISO  646, including
> US ASCII, and all characters  in  the  subset  are also  represented
> identically  in  all  versions of EBCDIC.

[RFC 1113](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1113) makes the following point:

> These characters, identified in Table 0, are selected so as to be
> universally representable, and the set excludes characters with
> particular significance to SMTP (e.g., ".", "`<CR>`", "`<LF>`").

Of the characters you specifically suggest, `@`, `#` and `^` do not exist in many variants of [ISO 646](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_646) (which were in common use in the early 1990s).

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about `,` but `.` was probably avoided because lines starting with `.` could trip mailers into thinking the end of input had been reached.